# Is it necessary for all these checks in my boss's django code?

Tags: python, django

This is my boss's code:

```
if hasattr(request, 'rk_user') and request.rk_user:
            request.rk_user.focus_update()
```

but i think it is not necessary to check both

I think it should be either:

```
if hasattr(request, 'rk_user') :
            request.rk_user.focus_update()
```

or:

```
if  request.rk_user:
            request.rk_user.focus_update()
```

Am I right?

Comment: Why do you not always have the attribute defined and valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the other answerers are right that they check different things, you can collapse the two checks into a single command:

```
if getattr(request, 'rk_user', None):
```

This gets the attribute if it exists, and if not, gets None; then it checks that whatever value it got is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

They check for different things.  One checks to make sure accessing `request.rk_user` won't fail (`hasattr`) and the other checks that it's not some `False`-like type, most likely `None` (the latter part of the conditional).  If he really wanted to go with guarded programming style, he could do:

```
if hasattr(request, `rk_user`) and request.rk_user \
  and hasattr(request.rk_user, 'focus_update') \
  and callable(request.rk_user.focus_update):
    request.rk_user.focus_update()
```

But that's just silly and onerous, which is why the more Pythonic style is to just try and handle the exception.  It even has an acronym, EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission), and it's [in the Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp).

So, neither of you is more right than the other.  If there are common cases where you'd expect the `request` not to have that attribute, then go ahead and check it.  If there are cases where even if it has that attribute, sometimes it's `None`, then it could be worth checking it.  But you're not going to really cover *all* your bases or exception-potential paths with any sort of conditional, so only check the stuff you might reasonably expect to happen and have logic to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `rk_user` is a custom attribute on the request model?  You should definitely include the `hasattr` if block.  And the other.  Your boss has the right code.

*EDIT*
I'm assuming that this can be null and you actually want the code to properly handle that condition.  Of course, if you are 100% certain that this value can never be null, feel free to leave the checking off, but think about future devs.